# Vignette is distorted and not symmetrical

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Situation: I am setting up a Vignette effect for my scene. Like what I do normally, I have a lens distortion node, math node (set to 'greater than'), blur node, and a mix node (set to multiply).

Problem: However, for this scene, the vignette effect seem to have a weird shape and it's not symmetrical either. Below is the result. How do I fix this? Thanks.
Here is my [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30460)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a vignette can be done much more simple by creating an ellipse mask node and tweaking the size value and then blurring it and multiply it with your image.

Comment: How is this simpler than using a method that uses relative dimensions, and thus always has the rigth size? While this works it's not the best option.

Answer (score 5):

That weird shape looks a hell of a lot like a distorted mountain to me. You shouldn't plug your source image into the Lens Distorsion. You could instead take a Distort-->Scale node, in Render Size mode, so that you have a totally white image.